Large model in gazebo slows RTF to 1%
I am loading a large fbx into gazebo (harmonic).  The fbx is a terrain model over a 2km.  Ive set the collision tolerances low but the RTF is extremely slow.  When I take out the model and just run the basic robot I have, RTF is 98% or so.
The robot is only interacting with a small portion of the model at a time.  Is there a way to speed this up, dynamically load in sections of the model, etc?
    <physics type="ode">
      <ode>
        <solver>
          <type>world</type>
        </solver>
        <constraints>
          <contact_max_correcting_vel>0.1</contact_max_correcting_vel>
          <contact_surface_layer>0.01</contact_surface_layer>
        </constraints>
      </ode>
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <!-- <real_time_factor>0</real_time_factor> -->
      <!-- <real_time_update_rate>500</real_time_update_rate> -->
    </physics>


Gazebo Sim supports 'levels' to split large worlds into sections.
I have no personal experience with this, but I assume that this can work if you split the terrain model into sections.

I was looking at that.  But is there a way to split it into levels without having to redesign the CAD file into chunks?  An auto split of some sort would be nice...

Afaik there is no auto-split functionality. Two suggestions: 1) instead of using the mesh as collision object, use a simplified mesh, or -preferably- create the collision from primitive shapes (box, cylinder, etc). E.g. try first with a 2 x 2 km flat surface (box object) and see if this yields a high enough RTF. If not, there's no point in pursuing this further. If so: refine the surface until the desired accuracy is reached. 2) Look into using a height map instead of an FBX. See e.g. the dem_moon demo world.

Gazebo Ionic has the ability to do automatic convex decomposition (see highlights). You can also use tools like https://github.com/cole-bsmr/SDFGen to decimate the mesh so it has a lower triangle count and replace parts of with primitive shapes as @JRTG mentioned.
